# Problem with chown directory

Tags: root, chown, readonly

i'm login with root account i want to chown my directory i do this:

```
[root@sop /]# chown -R webadm:webgrp /ap/P12B/
```

I have this error:

> chown: changement de propriétaire pour `/ap/P12B/': Système de
>   fichiers accessible en lecture seulement
>
> chown: changing ownership of `/ ap/P12B / ': file system read-only

My directory is mount like this:

```
/dev/vg_ap/lv_p12b           /ap/P12B             ext3    defaults        1 2
```

Comment: Please run again your command prefixing it with `LC_ALL=C`, this site uses English so French error messages are meaningless for most readers.

Comment: @jlliagre same problem

Comment: Sure, changing the locale wasn't a way to fix the problem, just to make it readable for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change anything on a read-only file system.

If the file system isn't implicitly (eg: iso) or explicitly (eg: -o ro) mounted in read-only mode, the root cause is likely some error where found and the OS decided to mount it read-only to avoid errors/damages.

You should look to the system message logs to see if anything is reported about your file system or the underlying volumes.

Comment: i can't do anything ?

Comment: You can first figure out why the file system is mounted read-only.